# Explorer open a library through command line

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

It is [possible to open a specific path using the explorer command line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510).

What is less clear is how to open one of the libraries listed in the side pane, like 'Favorites', 'Pictures', 'Desktop' or 'Computer'.

I tried simply passing those names, but that always seems to open up 'My Documents'.

Comment: It seems [this is possible by passing CLSIDs rather than a path](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm), looking into how to get those now ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Opening shell folders from the command line

The folders you're referring to are [shell folders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder), and you can't open them by simply passing their name as a parameter. A special syntax is required:

```
explorer shell:<FolderName>
```

The entire list is stored in the following registry key in Windows Vista and later:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions
```

Each subkey is a [Globally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) (GUID). The `Name` value is what you can use in the `shell:` syntax, which works regardless of the locale. See the related article below for other possible values (or just check the registry yourself).

### Examples

- **Computer** shell folder:

  ```
  explorer shell:MyComputerFolder
  ```

  You can also achieve the same result by using the shell folder GUID:

  ```
  explorer /e,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
  ```
- **Favorites** shell folder (not to be confused with Internet Explorer favorites):

  ```
  explorer shell:Links
  ```
- **Pictures library**:

  ```
  explorer shell:PicturesLibrary
  ```

## Further reading

- [Special folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder)
- [Shell Commands to Access the Special Folders in Windows 7/Vista/XP](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/)
- [The Windows Explorer Command Line](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm)
- [CLSID Key (GUID) Shortcuts List for Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13591-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-8-a.html)
- [KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The 'shell' syntax ain't working for me. The CLSID approach does. I'm currently programming a solution which looks up the CLSID. It is also important to take into account localization.

Comment: @StevenJeuris What results are you getting? It does work for me in Windows 7. The `shell:` syntax works regardless of the locale.

Comment: That's weird, now they work. Maybe it didn't temporarily since I'm messing with the registry simultaneously for the implementation I just mentioned. However, `explorer shell:Favorites` opens up the 'Favorites' folder in my user account folder, not the 'Favorites' star shell folder.

Comment: @StevenJeuris The Favorites folder is a per-user folder. Even if the path looks different in Windows Explorer address bar, you're accessing the very same folder.

Comment: Nope, I am talking about the list of 'Favorite' locations in the sidebar. The one with the star. By default it contains Desktop I believe, and if you install e.g. Dropbox it is added there.

Comment: My user account Favorites folder contains folders like `Favorites Bar`, `Microsoft Websites`, `MSN Websites`, `Windows Live`. No idea, never used this.

Comment: @StevenJeuris That's `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites`, usually located in the `C:\Users\<username>\Favorites` folder. You can open the folder by using `explorer shell:Favorites`.

Comment: As I said, that's not the one I was referring to (when I initially mentioned 'Favorites'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13460/discussion-between-and31415-and-steven-jeuris)