# Open Networks folder through cmd?

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, batch, cmd.exe

How can I open the networks folder (equivalent of click "networks" in windows explorer) from a batch file or cmd?

I thought I could just do `explorer \\` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### How can I open the networks folder from a batch file or cmd?

> equivalent of click "networks" in windows explorer

It's actually "Network" (singular) not "Networks".

Use the following command:

```
explorer shell:NetworkPlacesFolder
```

Source [How to Open Hidden System Folders with Windows’ Shell Command](https://www.howtogeek.com/257715/how-to-open-hidden-system-folders-with-windos-shell-command/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Shell Commands to Access the Special Folders in Windows 10/8/7/Vista/XP » Winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/)
- [windows 7 - Explorer open a library through command line - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/726378/explorer-open-a-library-through-command-line)

Answer (score 9):

To open special folders in Explorer, [use the *shell* command](http://arturmarques.com/wp/2014/05/22/how-to-create-shortcuts-to-clsids-in-windows/):

- *Network* folder: **`explorer shell:::{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}`**

Some other examples:

- *This computer*: `explorer shell:::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}`
- *Search dialog*: `explorer shell:::{9343812e-1c37-4a49-a12e-4b2d810d956b}`

Comment: Hmm. `shell:NetworkPlacesFolder` is both easier to type and to remember ...

Comment: True... I tried the GUID before you had posted... looks like we dis this almost simultaneously.

Comment: If you count 22 minutes earlier for my answer as almost ... :)

Comment: My browser was still open to the original post, which did not show your answer. Did not mean to step on your answer.

Comment: No probs ...... ;)

Comment: The shell code will work better during a system failure or corruption. The NetworkPlacesFolder refers to the shell code. So yours might be better for troubleshooting technically :D

Comment: I dare say the two answers are complementing each other nicely.  (+1 to both). Especially the 2nd one adds also the current Computer and the search Dialog) while the other Posts a shorter command that is easier to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Make a mapping to the shared folder :
net use z: \\

and close it afterwards :
net use z: /delete

Note:
see cmd : net use /? for help
z: = examplename driveletter
 : speaks for itself but every drive has a hidden administrative root share name : z$.